# Open Outlook window without freezing Tkinter GUI

Tags: tkinter, outlook, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to build an application that uses Tkinter and Python to display emails through Outlooks windows application. I am using Display(True) so that user can edit the email before sending. However, I see the application freezes/waits till the Outlook window is closed. How do I make the application just trigger Outlook and return back to business. The Outlook window can remain open in the background. I am not expecting any return value from it.

Comment: Depends on how you are triggering outlook. If you are using subprocess just use a nonblocking call like `subprocess.Popen` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `MailItem.Display(false)` (instead of true) to display the message modelessly.